# making some items unselectable in dropdownlist using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Dropdownlist i binded the values but in that dropdownlist just like group means(**employee,nonemployee**)  so that **items value** is empty(""), so i can use databound event split the two fileds ,that two fields i can apply the color and underline and bould and **user doesnot select that fields** , so pls see the below code and modify this code.

```
protected void ddlconsultant_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) { foreach (ListItem item in ((DropDownList)sender).Items) {

string r = item.Value; if (r == "") {

item.Attributes.Add("style", "color:Red;font-weight:bolder"); } }
```

thanks
hemanth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm handling this situation on the client side, using javascript, actually jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $("[id*=ddlConsultant] option[value='']").each(function () {
            $(this).attr("disabled", "true");
            $(this).css("color", "Red");
            $(this).css("font-weight", "bolder");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easier to do this with server-side code, in the same place where you set the colour of list items:

```
item.Attributes.Add("style", "color:Red;font-weight:bolder");
item.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
```

This will product HTML code that looks something like this:

```
<option style="color:Red;font-weight:bolder" disabled="disabled">item text</option>
```

I know this is kinda an old question, but I've just been looking for the same information, and having just found out, thought I'd add the answer here for completeness.

Comment: I am recommending your answer, because it's good for users did not allow javascript.

Comment: but it have a problem in postback